# discord.py Я хочу чтобы человека который создаёт канал сервере банило, при этом если он не является владельцем сервера!

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    if guild.member != guild.owner:
        member.ban()
```

Comment: какой предлог пропущен в словосочетании «канал сервере»?

Comment: Вопрос немного не по теме но запретить в настройках сервера создавать каналы не вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы узнать кто создал канал, проверим аудит:

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    async for entry in channel.guild.audit_logs(limit=10, action=discord.AuditLogAction.channel_create):
        if entry.target == channel and entry.user != channel.guild.owner:
            await entry.user.ban()
```